# Exclude results from List Comprehensions in Elixir

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

I have a simple list comprehension:

```ex
for x <- [some_list] do
  case _compute(x) do
    nil -> nil # directly exclude this value from output
    val -> val # add this value to output as usual
  end
end
```

Short of running the whole comprehension, and then filtering out `nil` values, is there a better was to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#generators-and-filters) support filters, generators, pattern matching and multiple clauses built-in.

**Filter `nil` values:**

```ex
for x <- list, !is_nil(x), do: x
```

**Call a new function on each value** (and automatically filter `nil`):

```ex
for x <- list, y = _compute(x), do: y
```

---

**Example:**

```ex
iex> list = [1, 2, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6, nil, 7, 8, nil, 9, nil, 0]
iex> for x <- list, !is_nil(x), do: x
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

iex> compute = fn x -> if x > 5, do: x end
iex> for x <- list, y = compute.(x), do: y
# => [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: in my case, `_compute(x)` may give a value or nil, hence i would need to run _compute(x) twice: i.e. test `_compute(x)` for nil, then do: `_compute(x)`

Comment: No need to run `_compute(x)` twice, as the 2nd form given will automatically filter `nil` values returned by `_compute(x)`.

Comment: I gave the example above to clarify how multiple clauses work, but you can shorten it even further with: `for x <- list, _compute(x), do: x`